# c# Не могу подключиться к postgresql которая на virtualbox

Tags: c#, postgresql, virtualbox

С официального сайта скачал .ovm файл для запуска сервера postgresql в виртуальной машине.
Запускаю, создал там бд, создал таблицу, добавил данные, всё работает.
В c# делаю соединение через Npgsql:

```
        bool boolfound = false;
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=192.168.56.101;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=4Oyat6gh7SfV;Database=postgres_db;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from postgresql", conn);
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                boolfound = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Connection established");
            }
            if (boolfound == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("bad things...");
            }
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Вызов conn.Open() выдает следующее: **Npgsql.NpgsqlException: "Failed to connect to 192.168.56.101:5432"
TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt**

Настройки следующие:
Сеть для машины - Виртуальный адаптер хоста

При запуске и выводе ip address адрес машины - 192.168.56.101

В настройках самого сервера файл postgresql.conf **listen_addresses = '*', port = '5432'** и в pg_hba.conf стоит **host all all 192.168.56.1/24 md5**

Машина из консоли винды пингуется, но c# отказывается подключаться. В чем может быть дело? А вот сервер не может пингануть 192.168.56.1 - адрес интерфейса который выдает команда ipconfig в консоли винды.

UPD:

пробовал так же сделать NAT сеть для машины, сделал проброс портов с хоста на гостя. В таком случае ошибка conn.Open(): **Npgsql.NpgsqlException: "Exception while reading from stream"**

UPD2:

делал просто сетевой мост в настройке vm для машины. Одна локальная сеть, 3 разных устройства в ней (сама вм, основной хост, второй ноут), всё пингуется во всех направлениях, а подключение к серверу просто не идет, без понятия что там нужно крутить в конфигах postgre сервера...

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145049/discussion-on-question-by-nx4n-c-----postgresql---v); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено:

1. Нужно использовать сетевой мост для машины в VBox
2. По умолчанию стоит nft firewall в debian(11) postgresql(15.2.0) машине, в его файле **/etc/nftables.conf** нужно включить 5432 порт на принятие внешних соединений

   chain inbound {

   ...

   tcp dport { 22,5432 } accept

   ...

   }

22 там и так стоит, это для ssh, далее перезапустить конфиг командой **sudo /usr/sbin/nft -f /etc/nftables.conf** (команда ничего не выведет при успешном выполнении). Настройка firewall на этом окончена.

3. Командой **ip address** узнать ip виртуальной машины в сети, в моем случае *192.168.204.52/24*, этот ip адрес нужно указать как принимающий соединения в файле **/opt/bitnami/posrgresql/conf/postgresql.conf**, строчка **listen_addresses** изначально неактивна и сервер принимает по localhost, убираем решетку перед строчкой, в итоге делаем **listen_addresses = '192.168.204.54'**
4. Далее нужно указать серверу в файле **/opt/bitnami/posrgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf** на то, что бы он принимал любые соединения от нашей подсети, добавляем строчку **host all all 192.168.204.0/24 md5**
5. Делаем перезапуск сервера **sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart**
6. Убеждаемся что сервер *already running* командой sudo **/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status**
7. Если *already running*, значит всё хорошо, пытаемся подключиться извне, что pgadmin, что c# должны подключаться в моем случае по адресу *192.168.204.52:5432*. Если **не already running**, значит где-то ошиблись при вводе параметров в nft, postgresql.conf или в pg_hba.conf